# How to add an external calculation to summary_rows fns = list(fn)

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

Could someone help me with adding another row to gt? I would like to add a row right below the `Total`. It seems like gt doesn't allow it because the call to gt() has been already made above. Data and code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

Data:
a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2012", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), F = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 0), W = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), S = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), LF = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), week = c("01", "02", "02", "01", 
"01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", 
"01"), month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January"
)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

a |>
  group_by(year, SampleDate) |>
  summarise(
    F = sum(F),
    W = sum(W),
    S = sum(S),
    LF = sum(LF),
    count = n()
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(across(year:SampleDate, as.character)) |>
  bind_rows()  |> 
  gt() |> 
  summary_rows(
    columns = F:count,
    fns = list(label = "Total", fn = "sum"),
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 0))

    ###Can another summary row be added to gt below "Total"?
    ### How can I pass the calculated values to "fn" below?
   summary_rows(
    columns = F:LF,
    fns = list(label = "std_error", fn = F = 1.96*(sd(F)/sqrt(length(F))),             
                                         W = 1.96*(sd(W)/sqrt(length(W))), 
                                         S = 1.96*(sd(S)/sqrt(length(S))), 
                                        LF = 1.96*(sd(LF)/sqrt(length(LF)))) |> gt()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because summary_rows is looking for a grouped data frame, and you need to use grand_summary_rows in its place.  Your `bind_rows` call seems to be redundant, so I would get rid of it. When it comes to calculating your standard error, you don't need to specify the function for each variable. I think this achieves what you are asking:

```
 a |>
  
  group_by(year, SampleDate) |>
    
  summarise(
    F = sum(F),
    W = sum(W),
    S = sum(S),
    LF = sum(LF),
    count = n()
  ) |>
    
  ungroup() |>
    
  mutate(across(year:SampleDate, as.character)) |>
    
 
  gt() |>
    
  grand_summary_rows( columns = where(is.numeric),  fns = list(label="Total",fn="sum" )) |>
  grand_summary_rows( columns = where(is.numeric), fns= list( fn = "std_error"~ 1.96*(sd(.x)/sqrt(length(.x)))))
```

There is no reason though why you could not do it in one call to grand_summary_rows though:

```
a |>
  
  group_by(year, SampleDate) |>
    
  summarise(
    F = sum(F),
    W = sum(W),
    S = sum(S),
    LF = sum(LF),
    count = n()
  ) |>
    
  ungroup() |>
    
  mutate(across(year:SampleDate, as.character)) |>
    
 
  gt() |>
  
  grand_summary_rows(columns = where(is.numeric),fns=list("Total"~sum(.) , "Standard Error"~ 1.96*(sd(.)/sqrt(length(.)))))
```

Or define the std err function ahead of time and call it as a named function:

```
    std_error <- function(x)   1.96*(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
    
    a |>
      
      group_by(year, SampleDate) |>
        
      summarise(
        F = sum(F),
        W = sum(W),
        S = sum(S),
        LF = sum(LF),
        count = n()
      ) |>
        
      ungroup() |>
        
      mutate(across(year:SampleDate, as.character)) |>gt() |>
  
  
  grand_summary_rows(columns = where(is.numeric),fns=list("sum", "std_error"))
```

Comment: I also woudl not use F as a vraible name as R may interpret it as FALSE in many instances

Comment: Thanks so much @BEVAN. I have a follow up question if you don't mind. How can I add another  grand_summary_rows()  `summing`  the `sum + std_error` rows`?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with how GT object properties to access the derived summaries similar to a data.frame, so I would just include the calculation in the list of functions in the first summary row. Ex: "Total Plus Error"~sum(.)+1.96*(sd(.)/sqrt(length(.)), or write it as another named function to call by name.